# SQL Ordering rows in a select with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to create an SQL Query to select rows from a database, ordered by a numerical field, however there are repeated entries in the table. 
The table consists of the following columns.

`UID` - Numerical Unique ID

`ACCOUNT_NAME` - Account Name, unchanged

`NICK_NAME` - Can be changed by the user at any time

`POINTS` - Records points held by the user's account

The goal of the query is to display the Account_Name ordered by Points. However, Account_Name is not unique and can appear multiple times in the table. 
To deal with this I would like to display only the latest row for each Account_Name. 
This meaning that in the results from the select each Account_Name should only appear once. I am trying to have the selection be decided by the UID, meaning that I want only the row with the greatest UID where each account_name appears to be displayed.

I have tried the following without desired results. (The name of the table is `ACCOUNT`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.account_name , A.uid, A.points
FROM account A, account B
where A.account_name = B.account_name 
and A.points > 0
and A.uid >= B.uid
order by A.points DESC;
```

This doesn't give me the desired results, specifically, there is an account in the database where an outdated row exists with a high value in the `Points` column. This record appears as the first result in the select, even though it is outdated.

How would you recommend adjusting this Query to select the desired information?

I hope this is enough information to work off of (first time posting a question) Thank you for you help :)

EDIT: Adding in examples with data.

Sample Table Data:
[Sample Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flBNe.png)

Current Results: 
[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJbQY.png)

Desired Results:
[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEH1A.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Sure, I'll update shortly with examples.

Comment: What makes a record "outdated"? You may want to add an "and" condition in the WHERE clause that filters out the outdated records.

Comment: A record is outdated when there is another record in the table with the same ```ACCOUNT_NAME``` but a greater ```UID```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining on an aggregate query calculating `MAX(UID)`

```
SELECT a.account_name, a.uid, a.points
FROM account a
INNER JOIN 
  (
   SELECT account_name, MAX(uid) AS max_uid
   FROM account
   GROUP BY account_name
  ) agg 
  ON a.account_name = agg.account_name
  AND a.uid = agg.max_uid)
WHERE a.points > 0  
ORDER by a.points DESC;
```

Alternatively, with MySQL 8.0, consider a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html):

```
SELECT a.account_name, a.uid, a.points
FROM account a    
WHERE a.points > 0  
  AND a.uid = MAX(a.uid) OVER (PARTITION BY a.account_name)
ORDER by a.points DESC;
```